# How to adb connect to android emulator inside Docker container?

Tags: android, adb

I start a Docker container from [`budtmo/docker-android-x86-8.1`](https://github.com/budtmo/docker-android):

```sh
docker run --privileged -d --name foo -p 4723:4723 -p 5555:5555 \
  -e DEVICE="Samsung Galaxy S6" \
  -e APPIUM=true \
  budtmo/docker-android-x86-8.1
```

Then, I'm trying to connect to it from my host machine:

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555
```

I'm getting:

```
failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:5555': Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try these commands

adb kill-server

adb start-server

adb connect localhost:5555    // or {localhost ip address}:5555

This will work if port 5555 is exposed